# Struggling with a Form of Logarithm question during my revision

Tags: logarithms

I am doing AS Mathematics In the UK under the examining board edexcel.

I came across this question in a List of exam questions given to me by my teacher However I can't work out how to do it.

> $$2^x  4^{x+1} = 8$$

Now I understand that $4^{x+1}$ is the same as $(2^2)^x$ therefore the $\log$ is base $2$.

So $\log$ base $2$ of $8$ = 3

And then I'm stuck. Can anyone help me on this? It'd be greatly appreciated :D

Answer (score 1):

Use the fact that $2^x 4^{x+1} = 2^x 2^{2 x + 2}= 2^{3x + 2}$ and $8 = 2^3$.